# C# Hook into Windows explorer folder changed event

Tags: c#, windows, events, hook, explorer

I've been searching around, with no luck, to see if there is a way to hook into the Windows explorer folder change event.

What I want it for is: if I'm browsing in my explorer (Windows 7) I want to run a specific set of code (key combo send) after the folder has changed.

Anyone know if this is possible? Thank you :)